# Constructor Code Not Called For Injectable Singleton Class

Tags: angular

I have created a service which is defined as a singleton and then provided to my AppModule. However when the app loads the code inside the services constructor is not ran. What might I be missing here?

MyService.service.ts

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyService {
  constructor() {
    alert('HELLO');
  }
}
```

AppModule.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [ ... ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    MyService,
    ...,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: where are you injecting it? if there is no injection, it maybe got tree-shaken

Comment: Does providing it to the module not inject it?

Comment: I did try providing it in the constructor of the AppComponent as well but I removed it because it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: true, did not see it was provided 2 times

Comment: Possible related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502757/angular-service-singleton-constructor-called-multiple-times

Comment: That seems to be related to it being called multiple times not zero times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular services are instianted when they are first requested by the DI system.

You need to inject `MyService` in a component for example for the constructor to be triggered.

Comment: I had tried to add it to the AppComponent but the constructor still wasn't called. I also tried adding a public method and calling it from the AppComponent and got a build error that the method wasn't defined. That's possibly a clue.

Comment: I needed to both project and inject it into the component.